# How to decrypt a message using only session key?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, decryption

I can view a session key to the encrypted data using option `gpg --show-session-key <file>`.
Knowing the session key, how can i decrypt the data without using my private key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To encrypt a file for a recipient:

```
$ gpg -ea -r foo@example.com < file > file.gpg
```

To get the session key for an encrypted file when you have the private key of the recipient:

```
$ gpg --show-session-key < file.gpg
...
gpg: session key: `9:901D6ED579AFF935F9F157A5198BCE48B50AD87345DEADBA06F42C5D018C78CC'
...
```

To use this session key to decrypt the file, without needing the private key:

```
$ gpg --override-session-key 9:901D6ED579AFF935F9F157A5198BCE48B50AD87345DEADBA06F42C5D018C78CC -d < file.gpg
```

This information was obtained by simply having a look at the man page for gpg:

```
--show-session-key
   Display the session key used for one message. 
   See --override-session-key for the counterpart of this option
   ...
--override-session-key string
  Don't use the public key but the session key string.
```

Comment: Oh, yea. I saw this option, but i didn't read the description to the end because the word "override" confused me. I thought that i understood a meaning of this option just after reading it. Thank you!